# Let's pick an icon for codegolf.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

This 'beta' icon for codegolf.SE is pretty lame.

So, in order to create a framework for my own proposal (*I dare you to do better!*), I ask "**What's a good icon for Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf?**"

Comment: ... **and** programming puzzles.

Comment: "my own proposal"?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of an icon which represents puzzles, why not an icon which is a puzzle? Maybe something encoded in the 256 possible pixels of the 16x16 icon?

EDIT: Thinking about it further, 256 bits could hold 32 ASCII characters, which might be enough to hold a J or Golfscript program...

EDIT2: :-) The ridiculousness continues...

Maybe convert the following to an icon?

```
0100111101100011
0011011011011100
1001110000110111
0110011001000011
1101011110000010
0001101000111101
1011110111111011
1101101110011011
1010001000010101
1000100001100010
0111000011001011
1001101001000111
0000110110111001
1101000100100111
1111011010100011
1110101001010000
```

With apologies to Gnibbler for appropriating his code.

The icon would look like this:

[image: icon]

Comment: this is a bit ridiculous. i love the idea :D

Comment: My apologies. All the letters are present. NB it might be slightly more elegant to make the four spare pixels be the four corners and mark them as a 50-50 shade or as grey.

Comment: No problem. I thought about putting the 4 spares in the corners, but wasn't sure how they'd be identifiable as non-encoded. Your different colour idea's a good one.

Comment: The text "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" is 31 characters long.

Comment: @PhiNotPi I figured it would be more in keeping with the purpose of the site to encode the name in a Golfscript program than to encode it directly.

Comment: @PhiNotPi And what's the biggest signed number you can fit into 6 bits? 31!

Answer (score 6):

Picking up [Gareth](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/737/gareth)'s suggestion, why not make the icon a tiny bit of Piet code? Codel size could be 2 to be a bit easier to distinguish from noise, albeit with the problem that less code can be written.

But I think esoteric programming languages exemplify the recreational part of what we're doing here quite well, regardless of whether they are good for golfing or solving puzzles (Piet is definitely under-represented here).

Comment: Having taken you up on the challenge, I think I know why Piet is under-represented. It's immensely irritating to write, and the only interpreter which I was able to get working at all seems to be buggy. If you can get an interpreter working, let me know whether http://www.cheddarmonk.org/codegolf.gif works for you.

Comment: [npiet](http://www.bertnase.de/npiet/) says `codegolf.stackexcha` and then goes into an infinite loop apparently. [Casey](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1375/casey) created a Piet IDE and debugger ([PietCreator](https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator/wiki/)) which from what I saw so far is much better than the other existing options.

Comment: well, there you go. It works in PietDev. Who knows which interpreter is getting it right?

Comment: From past experience I'd say PietDev is wrong; when I still drew Piet programs with it it had the habit of assuming wrong colors in some places (or colors that are long gone at a particular codel). The infinite loop appears to happen between the `c` and the `g`,

Answer (score 5):

Stealing Keith's idea, here's a "code-grinder" constructed by reversing the Meta-Stack Overflow icon, adding some space for a "grinding chamber", an output chute, and some smaller *things* coming out.

[image: Code Grinder Icon]

Comment: I'm not sure this adequately addresses the "puzzle" side. :(

Comment: I like the idea, but I'm not sure it would look that well in smaller sizes.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Puzzle piece containing part of >!]

"Puzzle" is a lot easier to convey in a small icon while still having space for some code than "golf".

Comment: Do they have to be *so small?* When I snagged one to modify, it was 48x48.

Comment: @luserdroog, they can be larger, but in all the contexts I've ever seen them they're displayed at 16x16, so I would rather give a mockup at that size.

Comment: Understood. :-|

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably awful designer, but I decided to try using U+26F3 as an icon.

[image]

In 16x16, it looks way nicer.

[image] [image]

Comment: Your suggestion has already been posted here http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/788/12205

Answer (score 1):

John Tenniel's Illustration for *Alice in Wonderland* portraying Alice attempting to play Croquet with a flamingo and two hedgehogs.

http://www.gutenberg.org/files/114/114-h/114-h.htm#alice30

[image: Alice trying to play Croquet with a flamingo and two hedgehogs]

Perhaps with "x=x+1" on the hedgehog running away and "++x" on the one underfoot.

Comment: What does it look like scaled to 16px x 16px?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that. It just looks like some dots. :(

Comment: Yep, that's the really hard part of icon / logo design. You might be able to do something recognisable if you colour it, but given that there isn't really anywhere to see a "full-size" icon it has to make sense from just the 16x16.

Comment: There is a slightly larger set of icons displayed on the stackexchange profile page, under the accounts tab. But it's still nowhere near large enough to accomodate Alice. Maybe a Disney cell would be more "iconic".

Comment: I found this hilarious.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of some sort of [code grinder](http://www.artcrafthome.com/picts/PB/PB-CodeGrinder.gif).  I'm not sure you could make it very small and still be legible, though.

Comment: Yes, that seems much more workable than a flamingo.